Calculate the posterior distribution
How can I solve the letter (a)?
Discrete sample spaces: suppose there are N cable cars in San Francisco, numbered
sequentially from $1$ to $N$. You see a cable car at random; it is numbered $203$. You wish
to estimate $N$. (See Goodman, 1952, for a discussion and references to several versions of
this problem, and Jeffreys, 1961, Lee, 1989, and Jaynes, 2003, for Bayesian treatments.)
(a) Assume your prior distribution on $N$ is geometric with mean $100$; that is,
$$p(N) = (1/100)(99/100)^{N−1} \; , \;\text{for } N = 1, 2,....$$
What is your posterior distribution for N?
This exercise comes from the book Bayesian Data Analysis Third edition - Gelman, cap.2, exercise 10.
On the website of the book https://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book I found that
\begin{equation}
p(data|N) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{N} &, N \geq 203\\ 0 &, otherwise\end{cases}
\end{equation}
But I cannot understand how to get this result.
If someone can help me, I would appreciate it.
Thanks.

$p(data|N) = \frac{1}{N} , N \geq 203$ comes from saying the probability of seeing any particular value (from $1$ up to $N$) is $\frac1N$, and noting $N$ must be at least $203$ if you saw $203$.

Let $N$ denote the total number of cable cars, and $X$ denote the number of the observed cable car.  Since we are equally likely to observe any given cable car, it follows that
$$X\mid N\sim\textrm{Discrete Uniform}\left(1,2,\ldots,N\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\Pr\left\{ X=x\mid N\right\} =\begin{cases}
1/N, & x\in\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,N\right\} \\
0, & x\notin\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,N\right\} 
\end{cases}.$$
Although $N$ is unknown, we are told that it follows a Geometric prior distribution; i.e.,
$$N\sim\textrm{Geometric}\left(p=1/100\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow f_{N}\left(n\right)=\left(1/100\right)\left(99/100\right)^{n-1}$$
for $n\in\left\{ 1,2,\ldots\right\}.$
This allows us to write the posterior PMF of $N$ as:
$$f_{N\mid X}\left(n\mid X=x\right)=\dfrac{\Pr\left\{ X=x\mid n\right\} f_{N}\left(n\right)}{{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\Pr\left\{ X=x\mid i\right\} f_{N}\left(i\right)}$$
$$=\dfrac{\left(1/n\right)I_{\left[x\in\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,n\right\} \right]}\left(1/100\right)\left(99/100\right)^{n-1}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\left(1/i\right)I_{\left[x\in\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,i\right\} \right]}\left(1/100\right)\left(99/100\right)^{i-1}}.$$
Substituting $x=203$ into this expression yields
$$f_{N\mid X}\left(n\mid X=203\right)=\dfrac{\left(1/n\right)\left(1/100\right)\left(99/100\right)^{n-1}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{i=203}^{\infty}}\left(1/i\right)\left(1/100\right)\left(99/100\right)^{i-1}}$$
$$=\dfrac{\left(1/n\right)\left(99/100\right)^{n-1}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{i=203}^{\infty}}\left(1/i\right)\left(99/100\right)^{i-1}}$$
for $n\in\left\{ 203,204,\ldots\right\}.$
